# How do I allow an input to match, without being case sensitive?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm experimenting with a create username + sign in flow, but I'm wondering if I can somehow preserve the case sensitivity input of what the user has entered as a username to the list while still being able to not match the case while logging in.

```
username = []
app = True
while app:
    start = input("Do you want to add a user to the list?" + " ")
    if start == "yes":
        while start:
            newUsername = input("Add a username to the list:" + " ")
            username.append(newUsername.casefold())
            print(username)
            break
    if start == "no":
        while start:
            userLogin = input("Enter your username:" + " ")
            if userLogin.casefold() in username:
                print("Nice, welcome!")
                break
            else:
                print("Nope, not on the list.")
```

As of now, I'm saving it all in lowercase and demanding that the input converts to lower case as well, but I want a user such as "jOhN" be able to login like "JOHN" and still be valid.

Comment: So you want to store the original username (without `casefold`) but compare in a case-insensitive way for login? Two ideas: 1) instead of an `in username` check, loop over the usernames and compare each one via `casefold` 2) store a dictionary rather than a list, where the keys are the `casefold`ed username and the values are the original username, then you can still `if userLogin.casefold() in username` for login, but you can `original_username = username[userLogin.casefold()]` if you want to display the other

Comment: _if I can somehow preserve the case sensitivity input_ Of course.  Save the original input exactly as it was entered, and then make a _copy_ of that in a separate variable that's casefolded, or all lowercase, or all uppercase, or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining your code, you could just add `casefold()` at the check along with `any()`. This will store the user as it was inputted the first time when registering, but whenever checking if there's a match, both the `user` provided and the users in `username` list will be casefolded, and if there's a match it will be printed `Nice, welcome!` as expected:

```py
username = []
app = True
while app:
    start = input("Do you want to add a user to the list?" + " ")
    if start == "yes":
        while start:
            newUsername = input("Add a username to the list:" + " ")
            username.append(newUsername.casefold())
            print(username)
            break
    if start == "no":
        while start:
            userLogin = input("Enter your username:" + " ")
            if any(user.casefold() in userLogin.casefold() for user in username):
                print("Nice, welcome!")
                break
            else:
                print("Nope, not on the list.")
```